# Calculating the percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, percentage

I am trying to get the percentage completed of a project in my app. The percentage will be displayed by a plugin, however the plugin requires the SQL command to run the query and make the calculation.

Basically, a project will have a milestones assigned to the user. Each milestone will have a field to mark it as complete.

Milestones and the fields that are related to this milestone (milestone ID, Status, due date, etc) are all written to this table: eba_proj_status_ms. The status includes these values: Assigned, In Progress, Completed.

What I want the plugin to display is, the percentage of how many milestones are marked 'Completed' for the specific project. So once all milestones are marked completed, the plugin should display 100%. Because it's for a specific project, I know the where clause that needs to be incorporated. I just need help with calculating the percentage based on how many "Completed" entries there are.

I don't have a developer background as I am using a SQL platform to build this app. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one attempt:

```
select 100.0*count(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 end) 
     / count(1) as pctComplete
from eba_proj_status_ms
```

Similar as @Sam cd but without the sub-select

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which flavor of SQL you're using. This is for T-SQL.

One quick and dirty way is to declare 2 variables to get the number of completed tasks and then to get total tasks. Then select completed/total. This will give you a decimal format (0.50 instead of 50% - you can multiply by 100 if you need it to return 50 instead of 0.50)

```
DECLARE @total  INT
DECLARE @completed INT

SELECT @total = count(*) FROM eba_proj_status_ms

SELECT @completed = count(*) FROM eba_proj_status_ms WHERE [status] = 'Completed'

SELECT @completed / CAST(@total AS float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what @Tingo said but without variables:

```
select 
((select COUNT(*) from eba_proj_status_ms WHERE [status] = 'Completed') /
COUNT(*) as PctComplete) * 100
from eba_proj_status_ms
```